# QuicKeys: Can't assign Enter or Tab as hotkey

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macros

I'm having the problem of trying to assign either the Enter, Return, or Tab key as a hot key for a shortcut in QuicKeys, with or without any modifiers. It doesn't seem to recognize these keys.

Comment: What OS are you running? I used to use QuickKeys all the time, but it just got too flaky & there’s no more support from the devs.

Comment: Old one. macOS Sierra 10.12.6. Figured it out and submitted the answer here for posterity, and to help anyone else who might be running into the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

After much Googling, I finally found the answer in the user manual.

> When the Hot Key assignment
> window appears, click and hold your mouse button with your mouse cursor in the hot key field, and press the
> Enter key on your keyboard while still holding the mouse button down. Clicking and holding the mouse button
> is necessary to assign some keys as hot key triggers; Enter and Tab are two examples of such keys.

This wasn't very intuitive when using the app. Really wish they had some sort of UI tip/hint pop up when trying to assign one of these 'special' keys as a hot key.